# ASP.NET 5 web application works with web.cmd, but not under IIS Application

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET 5 application, published under **dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update1**.

I followed [this article](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html) to deploy it to IIS 8.5.

When I run it using the web.cmd manually - it works.

But when I run it under IIS, it emits **HTTP 404 (Not Found)**.

What could be the cause for that?

[This is the IIS setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNBDR.png) I am using.

This is the web.config:

```html
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="..\approot\web.cmd" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="..\logs\stdout.log" startupTimeLimit="3600"></httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And the project.json:

```js
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Nummularii.Common.dll": "1.0.0"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Admin.Common": "1.0.0-*"
      },
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.ServiceModel": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install" ],
    "prepare": "gulp"
  },

  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: @Fanda take a look at my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is a bug in RC1 when the web application is under a virtual directory ('admin' in my case).

See the following link for a **workaround**

[beta8 published app doesn't run on IIS 7.5](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/416)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a long shot, but I wonder if you have a space in any of the directory names which are part of the path to the project?  In RC1 this can prevent IIS Express from running the web application.  And possibly IIS.  At some levels of the error reporting chain this looks like a file not found error.  However at other levels it shows up as "An error occurred attempting to determine the process id of the DNX process hosting your application."

As I say, this is a bit of a long shot as it might not be your issue, but I thought it was worth mentioning since it could be.

See this github issue for more details: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1194