# IIS taking forever to launch an Asp.Net Core RC1 app

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

While developing locally on my machine I tried configuring an Asp.Net Core RC1 app just to make sure I still understand what it takes before going to our production server.

Browsing to the app after configuring and starting it from IIS is taking forever while loading the page in the browser. I remember that this worked fine 2 months ago when RC1 was first released (it was then that I installed httpPlatformHandler).

I tried with the empty sample app that prints "Hello World!" and the same thing happened. Also tried reinstalling httpPlatformHandler. Did I perhaps miss an update/announcement for RC1 or anything like that? I don't think I did, and searching for this issue shows no matches.

Comment: What is the meaning of "forever" ?  what do you see in the error logs? my psychic powers are a little weak today ;)

Comment: The thing is, running `web.cmd` works fine. Starting it from IIS just never finishes "loading". Are there logs for IIS itself? Though I don't think they will show me anything. No errors! Just keeps on loading.

Comment: yes, there are logs for IIS, add features to the server and add tracing (same place you added IIS), and look at the Windows logs to the very least. Also look in C:\inetpub\logs

Comment: I think it will stop trying after 3600 - this is the default timeout specified in the web.config file. Looks like either it could not start the process or it could start the process but cannot connect to it. See if dnx is started and running. See the event log. Configure logging in the web.config file and see there is anything interesting in the log. Catch startup errors and see if there were any errors.

Comment: is it in a  virtual directory? does the application pool account has permissions? have you looked at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34593536/asp-net-5-web-application-works-with-web-cmd-but-not-under-iis-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infinite loading occurs when IIS cannot find dnx.exe. That happens when the publish fails to include runtimes in its output. Solution: Use the `--runtime` flag when publishing. For details see the answer to [Infinity page loading when host ASP Net Core application in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427855/infinity-page-loading-when-host-asp-net-core-application-in-iis).